# WHERE NOT EXISTS Clause is only partially working

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Good Afternoon,

I am currently running a query with a WHERE NOT EXISTS, and it is working for a majority of my issues, but certain rows are being skipped. I've been working on figuring this out for about three hours and have had no luck.
Here's my table structure.

**ContractItems** (Items on a specific contract for a specific customer.)

```
| Manufacturer | Style | Color | Size | Sort |
|--------------|-------|-------|------|------|
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    |      |    0 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 2XL  |    6 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 3XL  |    7 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA |      |    0 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | 2XL  |    6 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | 3XL  |    7 |
```

**MPRODUCT** (Master Product List)

```
| Manufacturer | Style | Color | Size | Sort |
|--------------|-------|-------|------|------|
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | XS   |    1 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | S    |    2 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | M    |    3 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | L    |    4 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | XL   |    5 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 2XL  |    6 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 3XL  |    7 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 4XL  |    8 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 6XL  |   10 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | S    |    2 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | M    |    3 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | L    |    4 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | XL   |    5 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | 2XL  |    6 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | 3XL  |    7 |
```

So, I am using a WHERE NOT EXISTS clause to select sizes not present in the ContractItems table from the MPRODUCT table.
Here is the query I am running:

```
SELECT * FROM

    (SELECT

         ci.MANUFACTURER                [Vendor],
         ci.Style                       [Style],
         ci.Color                       [Color],
         ci.Item_Size                   [Size],
         mp.sort                        [Sort]

    from dbo.contractitems ci

    join MPRODUCT mp on mp.BARCODE = ci.barcode

    WHERE ci.Item_Size <> ''
    and con_num = 1068
    and con_store = 98
    and item_type = 0
    and ((mp.MANUFACTURER = 'LIB' and mp.STYLE = '586M') 
    or (mp.MANUFACTURER = 'SSA' and mp.STYLE = '08700'))

    UNION ALL

    SELECT

         mp.MANUFACTURER                [Vendor],
         mp.Style                       [Style],
         mp.Color                       [Color],
         mp.Item_Size                   [Size],
         mp.sort                        [Sort]


    FROM MPRODUCT MP

    join ContractItems as ci on

        CI.MANUFACTURER = MP.MANUFACTURER
    and CI.STYLE = MP.STYLE
    and CI.COLOR = MP.COLOR

    WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
       from dbo.contractitems ci
       WHERE ci.MANUFACTURER = mp.MANUFACTURER
            and ci.Style = mp.STYLE
            and ci.Color = mp.COLOR
            and ci.item_size = mp.item_size)

    and con_num = 1068
    and con_store = 98
    and item_type = 0
    and ((mp.MANUFACTURER = 'LIB' and mp.STYLE = '586M') 
    or (mp.MANUFACTURER = 'SSA' and mp.STYLE = '08700'))
    and ci.ITEM_SIZE = '')a

ORDER BY Vendor, Style, Color, Sort
```

This works for the SSA-08700, but not for the LIB-586M. Here is my result set.

**Results:**

```
| Manufacturer | Style | Color | Size | Sort |
|--------------|-------|-------|------|------|
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | XS   |    1 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 2XL  |    6 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 3XL  |    7 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | S    |    2 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | M    |    3 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | L    |    4 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | XL   |    5 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | 2XL  |    6 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | 3XL  |    7 |
```

**Expected Results:** Would mimic the MPRODUCT table, but pull the not seen price from the ContractItems table.

```
| Manufacturer | Style | Color | Size | Sort |
|--------------|-------|-------|------|------|
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | XS   |    1 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | S    |    2 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | M    |    3 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | L    |    4 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | XL   |    5 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 2XL  |    6 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 3XL  |    7 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 4XL  |    8 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 6XL  |   10 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | S    |    2 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | M    |    3 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | L    |    4 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | XL   |    5 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | 2XL  |    6 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | 3XL  |    7 |
```

Does anyone have any idea's on why it would only select the XS record for the LIB-586M but pulls all sizes for the others?

---

**Results before the Union:**

```
| Manufacturer | Style | Color | Size | Sort |
|--------------|-------|-------|------|------|
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 2XL  |    6 |
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | 3XL  |    7 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | 2XL  |    6 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | 3XL  |    7 |
```

**Results after the Union:**

```
| Manufacturer | Style | Color | Size | Sort |
|--------------|-------|-------|------|------|
| LIB          | 586M  | FL    | XS   |    1 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | S    |    2 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | M    |    3 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | L    |    4 |
| SSA          | 08700 | CHHEA | XL   |    5 |
```

Comment: Are you sure your wrong records are not retrieved by the first statement of your UNION ALL ? Because I think the NOT EXISTS only applies to the second statement

Comment: @OlivierDepriester. Yes, I am only getting the 2XL/3XL values before my union all (just ran it to double check).

I can't use code formatting here, so I added the results to the original post.

Comment: In your `WHERE` clause, just want to confirm this is what you want `... and ((mp.MANUFACTURER = 'LIB' and mp.STYLE = '586M' and mp.STYLE = '08700') or (mp.MANUFACTURER = 'SSA'))`

Comment: You need to wrap all your 'OR' conditions in paranthesis. If not then it will not evaluate them seperatly.

Comment: @Eric this is what I'm using, looks like I made a typo, but it does not change the data I get.  ```and ((mp.MANUFACTURER = 'LIB'
    and mp.STYLE = '586M') or (mp.MANUFACTURER = 'SSA' and mp.STYLE = '08700'))```

Comment: @briskovich was a typo, I've updated my post with the correct 'OR' conditions, but the results I am having are still the same.

Comment: What does your expected result set look like? Can you mock that up and add it to the post?

Comment: @EricBrandt I've gone ahead and done that, will essentially be the MPRODUCT table, but I am needing to pull the contract price verses the retail price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I don't know why this worked, but I added some more clauses to the WHERE NOT EXISTS clause, and it seemed to fix it right up.

Here's the working code:

```
SELECT * FROM

    (SELECT

        dbo.trim(ci.MANUFACTURER)      [Vendor],
        dbo.trim(ci.Style)             [Style],
        dbo.trim(ci.Color)             [Color],
        dbo.trim(ci.Item_Size)         [Size],
        ci.sort                        [Sort]

    from dbo.contractitems ci

    WHERE ci.Item_Size <> ''
    and ci.status = 0
    and con_num = 1068
    and con_store = 98

    UNION ALL

    SELECT

        MP.MANUFACTURER                [Vendor],
        MP.Style                       [Style],
        MP.Color                       [Color],
        MP.Item_Size                   [Size],
        Mp.SORT                        [Sort]

    FROM MPRODUCT MP

    join CITEM as ci on CI.MANUFACTURER = MP.MANUFACTURER and CI.STYLE = MP.STYLE and CI.COLOR = MP.COLOR

    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( select 1 from ContractItems ci

        where
                con_num = 1068
            and CON_STORE = 98
            and ci.status = 0
            and CI.MANUFACTURER = MP.MANUFACTURER
            AND CI.STYLE = MP.STYLE
            AND CI.ITEM_SIZE = MP.ITEM_SIZE
            AND CI.COLOR = MP.COLOR)

    and con_num = 1068
    and con_store = 98
    and item_type = 0
    and ci.item_size = ''
    and ci.STATUS = 0)a

ORDER BY Vendor, Style, Color, Sort
```